# ElasticSearch - Limit size of nested collection on Query Result

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-nested

If I have blog-post with thousands (or hundred-thousands) of [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html) comments and I want to retrieve just the top 10 blog-posts. I will just use `size` to control how many blog-posts I want to retrieve, but I am not sure how to limit the size of how many `nested` comments I want.

e.g. This will return top 10 blog-posts with unlimited comments

```
GET myblog/_search
{
   "size": 10,
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   }
}
```

I try [`inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html) but it doesn't work for me. When I used, I have to do a query in the nested-comments, I also disabled the source (to avoid retrieving post with all comments), and the inner_hits result will give me each comment with each post (redundant) even though in some cases it is the same parent-post. 
I also thought about [`parent-child`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html) approach, but this mean creates multiple request/queries.

Do you know how to limit the size of a nested collection in a query?

What I am looking for is to create a query that I can do something like get top 10 blog-posts with top 5 comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this query:

```
{
    "_source": false,
    "fields":["your_fields"],
   "size": 10,
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "inner_hits" : {
        "comments" : {
            "path" : { 
                "comments" : { 
                    "size":5,
                    "query" : {
                        "match_all": {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `inner_hits` seems the only way to go. I use `source`-`exclude` instead of the `fields`, to remove the nested-object(s) (e.g. the comments) from the main result.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/source-filtering-usage.html